# Event fired when caret position changes in Document?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, envdte

In my visual Studio 2012 extension I am getting the Active `EnvDTE.Document` using

```
windowEvents = dte2.Events.WindowEvents;
windowEvents.WindowActivated += WindowActivated;

private void WindowActivated(Window gotfocus, Window lostfocus)
{
    if (gotfocus.Type == vsWindowType.vsWindowTypeDocument)
    {
        ProcessDocument(gotfocus.Document);
    }            
}
```

I want to know when the caret position in the document changes, but I cannot find a suitable event to attach to. I have found some events like `textEditorEvents.LineChanged` but this only fires when the text is changed. The situation I need to deal with is when caret position is changed, but changed to the text are not made.

What is the best way to achieve this? Does such a Document event exist?

Comment: What is your scenario? What are you trying to make your extension do? It's quite possible you should be using the editor APIs and completely staying away from DTE.

Comment: When you select a test in a test runner it opens the file and moves to the line of the test. I need to know the line number that the caret  moves to (and therefore the line of the test) when the file is opened. The WindowActivated event always returns 1 because it is fired before the caret moves. I am happy to use whatever I can to get the right result.

Comment: And what are you going to do once you have that?

Comment: After that I am going to find some text that appears in next line and then open another file and navigate to the line number that appears in that bit of text. The file in question is a SpecFlow feature.cs file.

Comment: OK, so what we really have here is an XY problem. What test runner is this? What is your actual scenario?

Comment: I am using the Resharper test runner, but most (all?) integrated test runners have the same behaviour of going to the test in the test fixture when you click on a test. The aim is to get to the actual SpecFlow feature file (where the test is specified) in the correct location when a test is selected, instead of the machine generated feature.cs file which actually includes the test annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Grumble...I was hoping there was a more direct way for doing what you want.

For events, there is nothing that I know of in the EnvDTE interface that will do this. The core editor interface for seeing when the caret is explicitly positioned is [ITextCaret.PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextcaret.positionchanged.aspx). The way you would wire one up is to export an IWpfTextViewCreationListener, and when you get the TextViewCreated method called, you are handed the view, and the Caret property on it will have the event. You can then attach to the event normally and do what you want with it.

There are a few strange things you might run into with this approach, in general: first, you won't necessarily know if the caret navigation was done by the user or via some automated system. Second, don't expect repeat navigation to work either, because if I click on a unit test and that's what I already did, there won't be a caret navigation to intercept.

You might still be better off seeing if the specific test runners you care about allow for extensibility. Many runners are "pluggable", the adapter tells the runner where the source code is. Many adapters for many runners are open source, so making a simple fix there might result in a much better experience long term.